# why $1 saved in task_struct during linux context switch?

Tags: linux-kernel

the core of the Linux 2.6.11 context switch can be simplified as follows:

mov prev,%eax    //eax points to prev
mov next, %edx   //edx points to next
pushfl           //to satisfy compiler
pushl  %ebp      //to satisfy compiler
movl %esp,484(%eax)    //save esp in prev
movl 484(%edx), %esp   //load esp from next
movl $1f, 480(%eax)   //save 1f at prev
pushl 480(%edx)     //push 1f
jmp __switch_to
1: 
popl %ebp
popfl

Now, let us look to the relevant code in __switch_to. It takes the prev_p and next_p parameters from the eax and edx registers. Does a lot of work, and terminates with

movl %edi,%eax
 ret

My question is: Why saving $1f via the instruction movl $1f, 480(%eax) is necessary??? As far as I know, the addres $1f is a constant which is fixed by compiler and does not change during execution. Hence there is no point in saving it. Also, and most importantly, afaik switch_to macro is just used at one place in source code.

A second question is: Why jumping to __switch_to after pushing $1 via pushl 480(%edx) is necessary? __switch_to will return to $1 alright if we just call it regularly, via a call instruction.

Comment: It seems that this forms a fake stack frame so when the __switch_to function returns with `prev_p` and a `ret` command the flow goes to `1f` for the previous task.

Comment: The point is, $1f is the same for all tasks. It is the label that is given in the on the progran above, just before popfl. In other words, there is no "1f for the previous task". All programs use the same $1f. Hence it seems there is no need to allocate space for it in task_struct and save it at every context switch. I think I am missing something but cannot see what.

Comment: But `__switch_to` could be called from multiple places and `C` routines expect to have a return address to support this.  You could annotate `__switch_to` with a `naked` attribute and then put an in-line `asm` to jump back; that would save one instruction.  Not to mention that stack tracing wouldn't work.

Comment: as far as I know switch_to macro is used at just one place in linux, and that is within the function schedule(). so, $1f in the code above exists only at one point. It should not make any difference whether switch_to is called from one or many points. As for __switch_to, it is only called from within switch_to().  I still cannot see any reason to save $1f to task_struct at each context switch.